# Is it safe to upgrade to W10 1809 on a Surface Book 1?

Tags: windows-10-v1809

On my Surface Book 1 (i7/dGPU), I noticed that Windows Update doesn't offer me to upgrade to v1809 (I'm currently using 1803), although it has been released a long time ago.

So, is there a problem making this version unsafe to install on this laptop in particular (I know there has been problems with Intel SSDs, file deletion,etc...), or can I upgrade manually, using Windows 10 Update Assistant for instance ?

Comment: A better question is "How bad would it be for me if this update bricked my Surface?"  Do you have another laptop you can use to work while the Surface is broken?  Do you have the spare money so that getting another computer is possible?  Do you have unique data on the Surface that doesn't exist anywhere else, and why isn't it backed up regularly or automatically?  Do you have all of the installers and registration keys to restore your software if the Surface is broken?  Here's another way to put it: MS determined that the v1809 update was so dangerous, they blocked their own PCs from updating.

Comment: Since its re-release, 1809 is going through a slower staged roll out. This does not mean that they have blocked your computer from receiving it, they have just not advertised it to you, or your computer has a configuration or issue that Microsoft has determined is more likely to result in a problem.